# SQL Server error 42000 - must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently getting this error when trying to run my SQL query :

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server] Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".
>   42000 - [SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".

How can I fix it?

This is my full query :

```
declare  @StartDate DateTime = '2018-05-01';
declare @EndDate DateTime = '2018-05-31';

with t_Redemption as (
  select Customer, isNull(sum([v2_pointredeem]),0) [v2_pointredeem], isNull(sum([v5_Gift]),0) [v5_Gift]
  from (
    select isNull(c.[member id],'') as Customer,
           case when convert(date,r.[Redemption Date]) < Cast(@StartDate as date) then 
                  [TotalProductPoints]
                else 
                  0
           end as [v2_pointredeem],
           case when cast( r.[Redemption Date] as date) >= Cast( @StartDate as date) 
                     and cast( r.[Redemption Date] as date) <= Cast(@EndDate as date) then 
                  [TotalProductPoints]
                else 
                  0
           end as [v5_Gift]
    from QF_Redemption r
         left join qf_customer c on r.Customer = c.[ID]
  ) t
  group by Customer
),
t_Transaction as (
  select Customer, isNull(sum([v1]),0) [v1], isNull(sum([v4_SalesTransaction]),0) [v4_SalesTransaction], 
         isNull(sum([v3_ExpiredPoint]),0) [v3_ExpiredPoint], isNull(sum([v7_Expired]),0) [v7_Expired]
  from (
    select Customer,
           case when convert(date,[Transaction Date]) < Cast(@StartDate as date) then
                  (Cast(IsNull([ExtraPoints],0) as int)+Cast(IsNull([TotalPoints],0) as int)+Cast(IsNull([TotalMultiplier],0) as int))
                else 
                  0
           end as [v1],
           case when convert(date,[Transaction Date]) >= Cast(@StartDate as date) 
                     and convert(date,[Transaction Date]) <= Cast(@EndDate as date) then
                  (Cast(IsNull([ExtraPoints],0) as int)+Cast(IsNull([TotalPoints],0) as int)+Cast(IsNull([TotalMultiplier],0) as int))
                else 
                  0
           end as [v4_SalesTransaction],
           case when convert(date,[ValidityDate]) < Cast(@StartDate as date) then
                     -- When [ValidityDate] >= Cast(@StartDate as date) and [ValidityDate] <= Cast(@EndDate as date) then
                  ( Cast(IsNull([ExtraPoints],0) as int)+
                     Cast(IsNull([TotalPoints],0) as int)+
                     Cast(IsNull([TotalMultiplier],0) as int)-
                     Cast(IsNull([TotalPointsRedeemed], 0) as int))
                else 
                  0
           end as [v3_ExpiredPoint],
           case when convert(date,[ValidityDate]) >= Cast(@StartDate as date) 
                     and convert(date,[ValidityDate]) <= Cast(@EndDate as date) then 
                  ( Cast(IsNull([ExtraPoints],0) as int)+
                     Cast(IsNull([TotalPoints],0) as int)+
                     Cast(IsNull([TotalMultiplier],0) as int)-
                     Cast(IsNull([TotalPointsRedeemed], 0) as int))
                else 
                  0
           end as [v7_Expired]
  from QF_Transaction
  --where outlet = @Outlet
  ) t
  group by Customer
)

Select  'c' + customer , sum(v1)-sum(v2_pointredeem) - sum(v3_ExpiredPoint) as OB, sum(v4_SalesTransaction) SalesTransaction,sum(v5_Gift) Gift_Product,sum(v7_Expired) Expired 
from (
  select customer,v1, 0 v2_pointredeem,   v3_ExpiredPoint,   v4_SalesTransaction, 
         0 v5_Gift,   v7_Expired
  from t_Transaction

  union all

  select customer,0 v1, v2_pointredeem, 0 v3_ExpiredPoint, 0 v4_SalesTransaction,  v5_Gift, 0 v7_Expired
  from t_Redemption
) ttt
 --Where v4_SalesTransaction> 0 or v5_Gift> 0 or v7_Expired > 0
group by customer
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Cheers,
Lihardo

Comment: You are running a query for both `MySQL` and `SQL Server` ?

Comment: sorry, just for sql server

Comment: is that the full complete query ?

Comment: What'e the exact error message? You've only posted part of it.

Comment: @Squirrel no, just part of it

Comment: @DB101 already edited, thanks

Comment: That's definitely not the full query, you end your statement with a comma (`,`), and your CTE is never closed. Post the **FULL** query.

Comment: we can't help to identify the error you if you don't post the complete query

Comment: @Larnu i cant post complete query, maybe its too long so i cant post it with complete query

Comment: Maybe you could add a link to download your script. Without it, I don't know how we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already declared the @StartDate variable, your full script must have some GO statements inside.

You have to remove them (or re-declare your variable after the GO line), because they end the scope of your previously declared variables.

Comment: But i dont have GO statement inside

Comment: Then it's another problem. You'll need to upload your full script so we can see the problem, because it's not in the part that you show.

Comment: Here is the link [Script](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e7938384722d95b26a02d2b757bfc72f20180719055628/f48cbf) and if i remove the declare variable and replace all variable with date value its just works fine, how is it?

Comment: @LihardoS I don't see anything wrong with your query that could cause your variable to run out of scope. But I have idented your code, so it's much easier to read and I posted it on the question. Let's see if someone else can help you.

Comment: Thank you, by the way i use navicat to run that script, is there any different way to declare variable for navicat?

Comment: @LihardoS I have never used navicat, but it shouldn't declare variables any different.

Comment: @LihardoS You may want to delete this post and create a new one, asking again for assistance (so it will appear on top of the new questions). If you do that, remember to this time include the full SQL query, preferably on the idented format (you can copy it editing the current question).